# "Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.App" when trying to execute Maven-generated Jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, program-entry-point, mainclass

I'm trying to build a maven java program on on Windows7 and my java -version is 1.7.  I'm getting this error:

> "Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.App" when trying to execute Maven-generated Jar

even though `com/mycompany/App.class` exists within the Jar and it has a main method. Here is what my `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: me
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_03
Main-Class: com.mycompany.App
Class-Path: C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/commons/2.1-SNAPSHOT/commons-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I'm trying to execute the jar using:

```
java -jar mycompany-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 12:141678 1
```

There is a blank line at the end of my Manifest file. I'm using Maven 3.0.5 and using mvn package to generate the jar file. Here is a portion of my pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathLayoutType>repository</classpathLayoutType>
                    <classpathPrefix>${settings.localRepository}</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Can someone help me understand what is causing this error?

Comment: Could you please post the full exception?

Comment: The error in quotes in the title is actually the full exception.

Comment: You need to package your dependencies as jars and include them in with your generated jar.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove everything from manifest except the mainClass, it should work.
If you are trying to create an executable jar file that includes all of the classpath
dependencies, you probably want to use either the assembly plugin or the shade plugin 
instead of the jar plugin.

Comment: This worked well for me using this setup: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Answer (score 0):

- assuming you have already checked that those files exist:

> ./mycompany-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/commons/2.1-SNAPSHOT/commons-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

- Does the artifact contain `com/mycompany/App.class` ?

`jar -tf mycompany-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

- Running java with the option `-verbose:class` can show how the classpath is resolved to load *(or not)* each class.

#### Note

You might have a warning at build time because no version is specified for the plugin:

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    ...
```

Comment: 1. I've checked and they both exist.
2. Yes, the jar contains App.class in the appropriate directory structure
3. I did try it with the verbose class, but all it showed were the Java classes being loaded.
4. You are right about the version, I have added it in.